# how elasticsearch exclude a specific value?

Tags: elasticsearch

A filed named as TenantId and it is value is in TenantId[*] format. 
I want to exclude the value like TenanId[] from query result.

my query string is:

```
    {
       "query": {
          "filtered": {
             "query": {
                "match": {
                  "type": "sld"
               }
             },
             "filter": {
                "not": {
                   "term": {
                      "TenantId": "TenantId[]"
                   }
                }
             }
          }
       }
}
```

but the result was still include the "TenantId[]".
Is there any way to do this?

Comment: this field is analyzed field

Comment: Please mention the mapping which contains the field `TenantId`.

Comment: What is the analyzer you are using for your field "TenantId". The outcome of the query will depend on that.

Comment: it's solved. cause this filed is analyzed filed, so if the text has string "tenant", it will be selected. Use TenantId.raw can solved this problem